# NameError: global name 'Anything' is not defined ODOO 10

Tags: python, function, odoo, odoo-10, email-threading

Hi when i try a fucntion to get one2many track_visibility in odoo 10 , when i click on save it throws me this error:

**NameError: global name 'Anything' is not defined**

This is My code :

```
class TransportManagementLines(models.Model):

    
    _name = 'transport.management.lines'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread','ir.needaction_mixin']
    _description = 'Transport Management Lines'
    _rec_name = 'chauffeur'
    

    lines_id = fields.Many2one('transport.management',string="Crée Par")
    chauffeur = fields.Many2one('transport.management.matricule',string='Nom Chauffeur', required="1")
```

This is the function i use:

```
 @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
                res = super(Anything, self).create(vals)
                if vals:
                    message = "Changes info"
                    res.lines_id.message_post(message)
                return res
```

Comment: It looks like you have note defined the variable `Anything` in the code.

Comment: How i can define that ?

Comment: Based on the code you posted `Anything` should be replaced with `TransportManagementLines`. See https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html for more information

Comment: it solve that error Thanks for you help but when i change a one2many fields nothing shows in the chatter log like if i change a field called state from accept to delete nothing shows